# Turn a lazy graph into a strict graph without mutation - OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Assume I have a (directed) graph with nodes of type

```
type lazy_node_t = LazyNode of int * lazy_node_t Lazy.t list;;
```

where the first `int` is an arbitrary tag, and the list is a list of lazy nodes accessible from the current node.

Is there any way I can turn this into a graph of `type node_t = Node of int * node_t list`, *without using any mutable values*? I realize it's possible using arrays, for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why you want to avoid mutable values, but I assume the reason implies that efficiency is not an issue.

In principle you can turn any algorithm that uses mutable values into one that doesn't. In the case of arrays in particular, you can use `Map.Make(Int).t` instead, where `Int` is `struct type t=int let compare=compare end`.

UPDATE:

Just to clarify: With what I have in mind the integers in the module `Int` do not have anything to do with the graph tags. They are indices into the replacement for the arrays.

My answer is based on the assumption, though, that you need the arrays only as intermediate structures. That is you have a solution using arrays that outputs the desired value of type `node_t = Node of int * node_t list`. Jeffrey Scofield's answer suggests that I might have misunderstood; that you only have a solution that outputs a value of type `node_t = Node of int * node_t array`. In that case my answer is of no help.

Comment: Does `compare` really work here? I would expect that two nodes with the same `int` and an empty set of successors would be considered equal, which is probably not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had not thought this through, so I foolishly thought the difficulty stemmed from the fact that I didn't want to use mutable values. I didn't think about the fact that it's always possible to avoid mutation. I think my idea with arrays does generate an array instead of a list, so it wouldn't work, but thanks for clarifying things!

Answer (score 2):

If you can bind names to all the nodes in your result you can create cyclic structures with `let rec`. For the general case, you can't give names to all the nodes. So there's no way to make a cyclic structure without mutability. This, at least, is what I've concluded.

Answer (score 1):

A second answer, according to my second interpretation of your question.

There is a way, but it is ugly. And we have to use a slightly different type:

```
type node_immutable = {
  tag_immutable : int;
  out_neighbours_immutable : node_immutable list;
}
```

Then, we exploit the fact that mutability has no influence on the internal representation of values. So the following type

```
type node_mutable = {
  mutable tag_mutable : int;
  mutable out_neighbours_mutable : node_mutable list;
}
```

is internally indistinguishable from `node_immutable`. So we can create a mutable version of a graph like so:

```
let rec mutable_node1 = {tag_mutable=1; out_neighbours_mutable=[mutable_node2];}
  and mutable_node2 = {tag_mutable=2; out_neighbours_mutable=[mutable_node3];}
  and mutable_node3 = {tag_mutable=3; out_neighbours_mutable=[mutable_node1];}
```

and then create an immutable copy through marshalling:

```
let node1 = (
  Marshal.from_string (Marshal.to_string mutable_node1 []) 0
  : node_immutable)
```

Comment: That's a clever hack, I didn't know about Marshal in OCaml! I'd be interested in knowing if there's a way to do it without bypassing the type system; intuitively I feel like there isn't.